# Efficient MySQL Queries on a Normalized Table with Complex and/or Conditions

Tags: mysql, database, normalization, database-normalization

I have the following table:

```
create table x (
    id integer, 
    property integer
);
```

I need to efficiently run queries that test multiple property values for a given id.  For instance, I may want a query that gets all ids with a property satisfying the condition: *1 and not (2 or 3 or 4 or 5)*.

If all my properties were in boolean columns ('t1' = true if property value 1 exists for id, false otherwise, etc...), then I can simply run this very fast query (assume y were such a table):

```
select * from y where t1 and not (t2 or t3 or t4 or t5);
```

Unfortunately, I have thousands of properties, so this won't do.  Furthermore, there's no rhyme or reason as to the queries, so while I can bundle groups of properties into conceptual relations, the query boundaries don't respect that.  Additionally, these queries are (indirectly) determined by the user, so creating views in anticipation of them won't help.  Finally, we'll constantly be adding data sets with new properties whose relations may be new, vague or cross-cutting, meaning that trying to create tables of relations may become a maintenance nightmare.

Hence why I chose the original schema.

To try to accomplish my queries, I tried first creating a pivot on the fields involved in the query, then querying that:

```
create table pivot as (
    select 
        id,
        max(if(property=1,true,false)) as 't1',
        max(if(property=2,true,false)) as 't2',
        max(if(property=3,true,false)) as 't3',
        max(if(property=4,true,false)) as 't4',
        max(if(property=5,true,false)) as 't5'
    from x);
select * from pivot where t1 and not (t2 or t3 or t4 or t5);
```

However, this is very slow.  In fact, it's slower than an un-optimized home-brewed solution.

I know I can produce complex queries with sub-queries, but a limited test suggested that performance would be even worse (unless I structured the query incorrectly).

What can I do to speed up my queries?

Comment: What makes you think huge is too huge?

Comment: It's too huge because it's > MySQL's max # of columns (4,096). Splitting the data into multiple tables can get around this, but at the expense of querying across multiple tables -- and there could be thousands of tables.

Comment: What rows go in the table? Presumably the booleans are calculated from other information so there may be a way to encode the entire table differently.

Comment: @philipxy -- I don't understand what you mean by "what rows go in the table?".  Very few booleans are calculated.  The vast majority are measured. So each property is a measurement id.

Comment: Measured: ok. Re "what rows go in the table?": Some rows are a table and some are not. For each base table row matching the heading, we decide whether it goes in. Eg Employee(i,n,a) is the rows where "employee [i] has name [n] and lives at [a]". They "satisfy" the "characteristic predicate" of the "relation". The characteristic predicate is usually what we mean by "the meaning" of a table. I could have said, can you normalize the boolean table. Normalizing tables is removing ANDs from characteristic predicates.

Comment: @philpxy -- Thanks! I can do this, but I'm storing multiple studies with different relations and specific relation "columns".  Plus my queries cut across relational boundaries.  For instance, study 1 has relations A,B,C while study 2 has relations A,X,Y (and some different rows for relation A).  Then I may query some "columns" in A across some in C or some in "columns" in A across study boundaries. I know I can construct my queries to cut across table boundaries, but with everything this open-ended, I wonder if the best approach is to treat all questions uniformly.

Comment: It might help you get the best solution if your question gave an example showing the important properties of your schema, since the answer is dependent on its details, especially since optimization is involved, rather than just design. Also some actual queries showing how you are combining tables and properties. EAV seems possibly involved. Also, part of the requirement may be how nice the querying syntax is? Meanwhile I have edited my answer with a VIEW for x(id,p1,...).

Comment: That's the problem; every property is important, and no property is more or less likely than another; this is a free-form query.  Although I'd like a clean query syntax, I can live with ugly queries, provided they perform well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `id` is not unique and an existing record `(some_id, property_id)` means that the property is `on`.

First, I would notice that `I need to efficiently run queries that test multiple property values for a given id` and `I may want a query that gets all ids with a property satisfying the condition: 1 and not (2 or 3 or 4 or 5)` may lead to completely different queries.

But here is my idea. Some more assumptions:

- there is always a positive condition that cuts away a significant part of ids (otherwise I would join several properties into an extra one that becomes such a condition)
- any pair `(id, property)` is unique (an you even have the corresponding UNIQUE index)

Now, if you have an index on `(property, id)`, then the following query will take all matching `ids` from the covering index (that is quickly):

```
SELECT id
FROM t1 
WHERE property = 150;
```

If this query leads to a significantly smaller result set than the whole table, you can afford to make another fast correlated subquery for another property that will significantly decrease the result set. This subquery will require another covering index `(id, property)` and the corresponding UNIQUE index is what it needs:

```
SELECT id
FROM t1 
WHERE property = 150 
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM t2
    WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.property = 130
  )
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM t2
    WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.property = 90
  );
```

If an earlier correlated subquery results to false, all the following subqueries will not be executed for the row. That is why the order is crucial.

You will need to play with the properties order, and probably hardcode that in the code that executes the query.

UPD: then, I afraid, you do not have much choice. The best you can do is to walk through the index in a single pass and compute what you need. The speed of the query then will mainly depend on the number of rows in your table. So, again assuming you have the UNIQUE index on (id, property), you can write something like:

```
SELECT id
FROM t1
GROUP BY id
HAVING 
  COUNT(IF(property=150, 1, NULL))
  AND NOT COUNT(IF(property=130, 1, NULL))
  AND NOT COUNT(IF(property=90, 1, NULL));
```

Comment: Your assumptions are correct, and I was hoping to avoid this answer :).  Since users determine the queries, it would take some logic to optimally structure them.  I'd go from a straight-forward mapping to a non-trivial (and possibly intractable) optimization problem.  So far, what I know (and the responses I received) are hinting I'm better off with my proprietary file format.

Comment: BINGO!  The Select/Having is much faster than previous queries I was using, and beats the home-brewed solution.  Answer accepted, upvoted and bounty awarded.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have:

```
P(id,property) -- thing [i] has property #[property]
```

and you want:

```
x(i,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5) -- thing [i] has property p1 per [p1] and ...
```

Does this suit your needs?

```
CREATE VIEW x AS
    SELECT id,
        property=p1 AS p1,
        property=p2 AS p2,
        property=p3 AS p3,
        property=p4 AS p4,
        property=p5 AS p5
    FROM P
```

Presumably you are doing something like this:

```
--  for A(id,...)
SELECT id,... FROM A JOIN x USING(id) WHERE t1 AND NOT (t2 OR t3 OR t4 OR t5)
```

where you want only the A rows with ids where P(id,t1) and not ... .

(In case you ever do make a table with multiple boolean columns that you would like to minimize storate for you can use BIT (1) (BIT (m) takes (m+7)/8 bytes). You can use them like booleans.

Do not encode multiple bits into values yourself, it stops the DBMS from optimizing.)

Comment: Thanks, but this is less efficient than the way I'm doing it now.  Right now, I just store the id and property if the value for that id, property pair is true.  If it's false, the entry doesn't get stored at all.  By using BIT, I'd end up not only having to add an extra column to the table, but then I'd also have to store all the false values.  I imagine that will slow down my queries and significantly increase my table size.

Comment: The "pivot table" can change each time, so no fixed views.  Also, I'm basically doing what the CREATE VIEW does, and doing it that way is no faster :(.  Also my query on the pivoted table doesn't need a join since by then all the column are in place, so a where clause is sufficient.

Comment: One can't *tell* whether you would need an expression inline vs view or that you need to incorporate it (ie P(id,property)) earlier (eg pre-pivoting) because you haven't posted relevant DDL. (Your own question gives a create table so I just echoed that.) You have not given enough information to answer your question. Optimization by definition is inadequacy of a semantically correct expression because the implementation cares about the particular syntax used. You have to give (minimal) example table definitions and problematic query. Preferably executable.

Comment: Actually, what I provided was the actual DDL and an actual sample query, with the field names changed.  I also profiled the queries, which is how I knew they were slower than a home-brewed solution.  If I'm missing something, please let me know.  I'll adjust the wording to make it clear this is my actual table and I'll throw in some hard numbers.

Comment: You have not given DDL and queries for everything relevant, eg A, B, C, X, Y, eg "user determined queries", eg what indexes are involved?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered building a table consisting of (id, propertybin), that gets populated as follows:

```
INSERT LookupTable (id, propertybin)
SELECT id, sum(1 << property)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY id
```

Now, propertybin holds a binary value for each ID, where each bit represents whether a property from 0 to 63 exists in MyTable. I realise you have more than 64 properties, but I think this idea could be expanded upon to hold more properties - since you now have 1 column able to hold information about 64 properties, you would "only" need, say 100 such columns to hold information of 6400 properties.

Now, to find all id's satisfying a certain condition, you would use bitwise logic. For example, to find all id's having property 0, but not 1, 2, 3 or 4, use:

```
SELECT id
FROM LookupTable
WHERE ((propertybin ^ 0x1E) & 0x1F) = 0x1F
```

Here, we use the exclusive-OR bitwise operator `^` together with the value 0x1E = binary 11110, to filter the not-criteria. We use the AND bitwise operator `&` with the value 0x1F = binary 11111, to indicate that we are only interested in the first 5 bits.

Alternatively, a sufficiently large column of type VARBINARY could possibly be used, eliminating the limitation of 64 properties per column. However, I'm unsure of the possibilities offered by MySQL to filter certain bits in a VARBINARY value.

Comment: Interesting idea, but unfortunately this would reduce the flexibility/extensibility that are the main reasons I'd want an RDBMS to begin with, so this isn't an option.